# Number of trials follows the binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

Two random variables follow the following Binomial distribution.
$N_i\sim B(S_i,\delta)$, $H_i \sim B(N_i,\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is not a function of $\delta$.

These two random variables are related in a sense that in each period i, $N_i$ is determined first then realized $N_i$ gets into $B(N_i,\alpha)$.

I am interested in calculating the following:
$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^T H_i}{\sum_{i=1}^T N_i}\right]$$

Let's assume that $N_1=1$ so that we don't consider the case where the denominator becomes zero.
Intuitively, this expected value would be alpha. 
However, how can I prove this mathematically?

Comment: Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site. Also, please make the title more specific and less redundant.

Comment: There is a positive probability that the denominator $\sum N(i)$ is zero. How do you define the ratio $\sum H(i)/\sum N(i)$ in that case?